# Addition layer semi-transparency

Tags: gimp, transparency

I'm trying to export a semi-transparent png. There is an addition layer with giving a bloom/glow(not really sure what to else call it) which shows up fine when there is a black background, but disappears when I hide the layer and/or export it.

I had a very similar problem in blender when making the model while exporting it. The only way to properly get around it was to export two layers, one with traansparency and one with a black background, and then in gimp reduce the lightness of the layer with transparency to zero, and set the mode for the layer with the background to addition.

I want to be able to export this as semi-transparent so I can composite it over a video without the hassle of having to export two files and set them up in the video editing.

[Here's the file if anyone can help](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eETusIf44zGHa6fnf8sQcBpaX6wK5xCD/view?usp=sharing) :)

With black background
[image: With background]
Without background (no bloom/glow D:)
[image: Without background no bloom]

Comment: Layer modes dont export. The addition glow wont export, so either you need to flatten the image or keep it opaque. In either case it wont behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, most layer blend modes (`Normal` is one exception) keep the opacity of the pixels over which the new layer is applied.

- When you have a background (`Layer` layer), all the pixels of the stack (composition of `Layer` and `sunT.png` layers) are opaque, so all the pixels of your `sun.png` apply to opaque pixels and have a visible result.
- When you remove `Layer`, for the black background and the glow the application of the `sun.png` blend mode occurs on pixels that are transparent in `sunT.png`, so the result is transparent. This is also why the black background in `sun.png` disappears in that case.

If you want a glow, add it in a layer below your sun and keep everything in `Normal` mode:

[image]

Result (without `Layer`):

[image]